# Bare minimum of learning in c++ (or what can I skip)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I'm currently cramming up on c++ in order to complete a specific task for my 3rd year Applied Computing degree project. Im by no means a programmer but I am going top have to program an App.

My most comfortable language is c# so this is what I will be using for the bulk of the logic in my app, however I will need to create a c++ DLL to get the values I need to work with in the app.

So, my question is, to save me having to go through everything from beggining to end in a begginners c++ book (as I am currently) what do i need to learn and what can I skip to be able to get values from 'wlanapi' (and by extension any other native api/library/dll) and make them available to my c# program?

As it stands I've been at it for a week and all i've covered is Declarations, Variables, Input/Output, Arithmetic Operators and am currently trudging through 'bitwise operators' (which I know i will never use).

**edit**

Ok, I'll be specific. What would be the c++ equivalent of of querying WMI classes in c# using ManagementObjectSearcher? In particular I wish to use the WlanAPI to get the RSSI and SSID's of multiple wireless AP's.

Many Thanks

Comment: Don't you already know most of the basic stuff from C#?

Comment: This doesn't belong on Stackoverflow, but you don't need to touch C++.

Comment: I felt i should go over it in case i miss anything important, it does seem most of the very basic stuff is similar but, for example, in c# i would use WMI via ObjectManagementSearcher and WQL, but that's what is very different in c++.

Comment: You need to learn all the important bits, like memory and pretty much all the complex bits that C# glossed over. Interestingly, the bits you might have been able to skip are the ones you haven't.

Comment: @peachykeen thanks, see edit for more specific question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WINAPI was originally designed for C. Because of this, you can skip over a lot of the C++ specific parts of C++.

Big stuff to skip:

- Objects
- Templates
- Anything in the STL (Standard Template Library)

  - Iterators
  - IO Streams
  - C++ Strings

Big stuff to focus on:

- Dynamic vs Static memory allocation
- Pointers
- Arrays
- C-strings

  - WINAPI provides safe alternatives for unsafe methods in `<cstring>`
  - WINAPI uses unicode, not ASCII.
- Structs

To be honest, there is no reason you should even be using C++. You should probably be using C for this instead.

Comment: thank @Swiss. Time dictated that I went for something a little more familiar than c that would still give me the ability to use native API. So, rightly or wrongly i went for c++.

Comment: If you use C++ instead of C without using the features specific to C++, you are really just making more work for yourself.

Comment: Is it really all that bad? I just wanted to get th RSSI and SSID'S of multiple AP'S and store them as values to be used ny my c# program. I gues i better get back on with my research :(

Comment: The C standard is only around 100 pages thick. The C++ standard is larger than your house.

Comment: holy smoke, thankyou so much. I just had a quick look around and found a c code example that is only about 10 lines long, just enough to get the variables and print them. Take out the output and we have next to no code. C it is then +1 :)